# How do I go from a normal distribution with a variance to uniform distribution with the same variance?

Tags: statistics, variance

you have some normal distribution with mean 0
and variance $^2$
and that you want the interval [,]
such that the uniform distribution on the interval has mean 0
and variance $^2$
?

This is my variance equation when the numbers are drawn from a normal distribution $$2/(n_{in}+1/n_{out})$$
The answer for the uniform distribution with the same variance is
$$6/(n_{in}+1/n_{out}),-6/(n_{in}+1/n_{out})$$
How exactly does the 6 come into play is it from the integral of the uniform distribution formula and how exactly does that work ? I understand why you need a range for a uniform distribution but I don't understand where the 6 comes from ?

for more context: n_in and n_out are the number of neurons into a layer and out of a layer of a neural network.  Here is the paper where I am getting the formulas from https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf     on page 5

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What are $n_{in}, n_{out}$?  What's a variance equation?

Comment: @lulu i added some more context

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are you just saying you have some normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and that you want the interval $[a,b]$ such that the uniform distribution on the interval has mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: @lulu yes exactly

Comment: just not sure how and why to get 6 in numerator

Comment: I suggest editing the question to reflect that...as it stands, it's very hard to follow.  You don't, for instance, mention the mean anywhere, I just guessed at that.

Comment: Did you look up the formula for the variance of a uniform distribution? It's got a 12 in it.

Comment: In any case, hint:  the mean being $0$ means we want $[-a,a]$ for some $a$.  The variance of the uniform distribution for that is $\frac 1{12}\times (2a)^2$.  Now just solve.